# How to get name of subclass from an instance of the superclass placed in another class?

Tags: java, inheritance

for example in the code below I want to get "Dog" or "Cat". How do I do that?

```
public class Animal {
    // insert code here
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    // insert code here
}

public class Cat extends Animal {
    // insert code here
}

public class test {
    Animal animal = new Animal();
    // how do I get the name of the subclass i.e. how to get that the 
    // animal is a dog if it is in fact a dog??!
}
```

Comment: Also, in this case, it will be an `Animal`, not a `Dog`, not a `Cat`.

Comment: As Sotirios Delimanolis has said, you can't, because you have only created an instance of Animal. You have never created an instance of a subclass of Animal.